# Using Processing, creating interactivity with an SVG

Tags: svg, processing

I am hoping I can find some help here, I've been researching and trying over and again but can't seem to find a solution. I am using processing 2.0.3.

I have an SVG file that is a map of US states. I have an excel sheet saved as a .csv with data for each state. I've been trying to find a way to click on the state on the displayed SVG file, and have it display some sort of graph from the data in the excel sheet.

My questions are: How do I make the SVG file clickable, and how do I link it to the data?
The solution I've seen around the internet is to create an invisible shape layer with all the states having a slightly different color, detecting that color on a click of the mouse will determine the color and read it from the data. I've attempted to recreate the examples I found but they are not making sense and I feel like I am at a wall. If anyone has any help or suggestions it would help a ton! Thanks in advance!

Code so far, most of it adapted from http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/need-help-with-mouse-over-text-box-display-on-us-map.html. Its not working... :/

```
PShape states;
PShape buff;
Table crime;
PGraphics pg;
int rowCount;
int start = 100;
int yrButton = 0;
float crimeButton = 0;
boolean mouseShowText = false;
String[] textToShow = {"HI","RI","CT","MA","ME","NH","VT","NY","NJ","FL","NC","OH","IN","IA",
 "CO","NV","PA","DE","MD","MI","WA","CA","OR","IL","MN","WI","DC","NM","VA","AK","GA","AL",
  "TN","AZ","UT","ND","SD","NE","MS","MO","AR","OK","KS","LA"};
void setup(){
  size(1000,700);
  crime = loadTable("crime.csv");
  states = loadShape("states.svg");
  rowCount = crime.getRowCount();
  pg = createGraphics(700,500);
  pg.beginDraw();
  pg.background(0);
  makeHiddenMap(textToShow);
  pg.endDraw();
  noLoop();
}

void draw(){
  background(222,250,248);
  fill(200);
  rect(0,0,575,400);
  shape(states,0,0,700,500);
}

void makeHiddenMap(String[] states){
  pg.stroke(255);
  for(int i=0;i<states.length;i++){
    PShape buff = states.getChild(states[i]);
    buff.disableStyle();
    pg.fill(count+10,0,0);
    pg.noStroke();
    pg.shape(buff,0,0);
    textToShow[count] = states[i] + winText;
    count++;
  }
}

void showMouseOver(){
  String textMouseOver=textToShow[numberOfState];
  if (!textMouseOver.equals("")){
    float posX=textX;
    float posY=textY;
    if (posX+textWidth(textMouseOver)+10 > width){
      posX=width-textWidth(textMouseOver)-12;
    }
    fill(255,255,44);
    rect(posX+14,posY+4,textWidth(textMouseOver)+5,20);
    fill(0);
    text(textMouseOver,posX+16,posY+4+16);
  }
}
```

Comment: The approach you posted is a common one. Maybe post some of the code that you have tried that doesn't work?

Comment: I've been going off this example, the last comment: http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/need-help-with-mouse-over-text-box-display-on-us-map.html But I am so lost just trying to read through it and modify it for my needs. I think I am just not understanding what needs to be done, and hoping for a clear explanation, rather than a wall of code.

Comment: Are you able to draw each US state of the svg? If you can draw each state sequentially instead of all at once, then you can draw to an offscreen buffer (using `PGraphics` or `PImage`) that's the same size as your program's canvas, using a different color for each state. Then, when you write the `mouseClicked()` event, you can use the x and y coordinates to check the color _in that offscreen buffer_ and determine what state it is from. Basically, you're translating clicks on the visible map to clicks on the virtual map and seeing which state matches the color.

Comment: @kevinsa5 I can show what I have so far, I am extremely new at this so I am not sure if they are individually drawn or not. Ill add what I have to the original post, I got most of it from the link in my previous comment

Comment: The part of your program relevant to this discussion is the `makeHiddenMap(String[] states)` function. In that function, you pass it an array, you loop through that array, drawing each state individually to the buffer. The line inside the for loop `pg.fill(count+10,0,0);` makes the color of each state different; specifically, each state will have a red value one greater than the one before it (because `count` is added by one iteration through the loop, and `fill` takes R,G,B parameters). However, there are several problems with this code-- `count` is never declared, duplicate `states`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, that clears a lot up. The examples I'm finding are great but I don't understand what does what. Thanks for your help! I'm new to stackoverflow but if there is any way I can upvote you or show thanks, let me know.