# Inserting map in GUI program on Processing

Tags: user-interface, processing

My task in a project is to create a dynamic visualisation using any large dataset/s. I'm thinking of having a map of a country and allowing the user to select any state in order to see that state's specific crime statistics (inputted through the data set). I have heard that Processing is good for such GUI's but I've only just downloaded the program today (and only know Java moderately). I've started learning basic functions in Processing using the controlP5 library function; however I'm unsure on how to input a map, and how to let user's select any single state.

Any tips/advice/help regarding the project would be appreciated :)

Comment: you need a map in ".svg" format, (maybe you will find one at wikipedia)
and then you can code it like its shown here  
https://lernprocessing.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/visualisierung-von-landerbezogenen-daten/
(it's in German, I'll translate that for you if "copy-paste" isn't successful)
... maybe this question is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894346/using-processing-creating-interactivity-with-an-svg

Comment: @JavaMan both links are very helpful, thank you!